# MVVMCross and Visual Studio Design mode: any way to set DataContext

Tags: mvvmcross

In the samples I found, binding in xaml is done like following (from TipCalc Phone):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}"></TextBlock>
```

Ofcourse it works at runtime; but in design mode, if I control-click that Total Property, VS does a Symbol Search and shows me result.

Been trying a lot of things, but can't seem to get it to go the viewModel property without the searching. What am I missing?

**SOLVED:**

Never mind; figured it out.. on the xaml page, I needed to put this at root node.

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:SettingsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

where vm is the namespace; now clicking on a binding property goes straight to the viewModel :)

I wonder why none of the samples have this; as it's a design context, it should have no affect on real application, right?

Comment: "i wonder why none of the samples have this" - the simple answer is just that the samples are there mainly to demonstrate and exercise the core features and they don't really have a lot of design beauty in them - so the xaml for tipcalc was hand crafted without the designer. Would love to see more samples and blogging about real apps with real designs. Will add to my todo list. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Stuart, took your advice and started a blog; not sure how useful it would be for others, but at-least it would be a reference point for me :) here is the link http://ranahossain.blogspot.co.uk/ [link](http://ranahossain.blogspot.co.uk/)

Answer (score 0):

well my own answer

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:SettingsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

has it's own drawback; none of my viewModel is constructor free, which means I can't have IsDesignTimeCreatable as True; I have a page where I use a list of countries and user selects one: selected item is an object with iso and country name. With DataContext, xaml in design view gives an error saying selectedItem in List can't be null (as that object doesn't exists); I used a Fallback = null, which is ugly and has it's own problem.

Currently the other method is using Sample Data file, which can be generated from class using Blend; it's not very good (as it can't refresh), but works.